# Function name from a variable in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I create a context-menu from an array like this:

```
var menu1 = [
   {
      'OPTION1':function(menuItem,menu) {
         // code for OPTION1
      }
   },
   {
      'OPTION2':function(menuItem,menu) {
         // code for OPTION2
      }
   }
];
```

When the user right-clicked on my webpage, a menu appears with the options OPTION1 and OPTION2.

I need to change dynamically the function name, because it's the context-menu option text. **Is there any way to declare the function name as a variable?**

This is what I want:

```
var optionsletters = {};
optionsletters['option1'] = 'option_one';
optionsletters['option2'] = 'option_two';

var menu1 = [
   {
      optionsletters['option1']:function(menuItem,menu) {
         // code for OPTION1
      }
   },
   {
      optionsletters['option2']:function(menuItem,menu) {
         // code for OPTION2
      }
   }
];
```

EDIT#1: This is the plugin I've been using [jQuery ContextMenu Plugin](http://www.javascripttoolbox.com/lib/contextmenu/index.php)

EDIT#2: I need this to allow change language from spanish to english and viceversa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the object literal notation to set arbritrary properties as you seem to try in the second example. This doesn't stop you from setting the property manualy:

```
function make_menu_item(name, func){
    var item = {};     //Create an empty object
    item[name] = func; //Assign the property with the name you choose
                       //(obj['option1'] is equivalent to obj.option1 in Javascript)
    return item;
}

var menu = [
     make_menu_item('option1', function () {...}),
     make_menu_item('option2', function () {...})]
```

Answer (score 1):

What about something like:

```
var name = 'option_one',
    optionsletters = {};
optionsletters[name] = function() { ... };
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking if you can change the key from 'OPTION1' : function() {} to 'option1' : function() {} ? If so you can just copy the function to a new variable onclick.  If what you're asking is to be able to call something 'option1' as a string like option1 but actually call OPTION1(){} you can try a few different things.  One you could make your array like so arr[{'name' : 'option1', 'func' : function(){} }] Then you could reference array[0].name and array[0].func.

With your current code it looks like you're blowing out your functions with strings.

JS is super expressive so there are a million ways to do anything. Functions are first-class objects so can be passed as parameters and even returned from functions.